# What is the antecedent of 'them' in Deutoronomy 3:4-6?

Tags: referent-identification, deuteronomy, moses

Deutoronomy 3:4-6 NASB

> 4 We captured all his cities at that time; there was not a city which we did not take from them: sixty cities, all the region of Argob, the kingdom of Og in Bashan. 5 All these were cities fortified with high walls, gates and bars, besides a great many [d]unwalled towns. 6 We [e]utterly destroyed ***them***, as we did to Sihon king of Heshbon, [f]utterly destroying [g]the men, women and children of every city.

What is the antecedent of 'them' in the above text?

Answer (score 1):

Back up a few verses to verse one:

> “Then we turned and went up the road to Bashan; and Og king of Bashan came out against us, he and all his people, to battle at Edrei. 2 And the LORD said to me, ‘Do not fear him, for I have delivered **him and all his people** and his land into your hand; you shall do to him as you did to Sihon king of the Amorites, who dwelt at Heshbon.’

Verse four:

> And we took all his cities at that time; there was not a city which we did not take from **them**...

In verse six, "them" could either refer to the city's walls and gates and bars or the king and his men.  Context implies the second possibility.  Furthermore, I'm no Hebrew expert, but the gender for "them" is masculine possibly implying that it refers to the people rather than the fortifications.  On the other hand, I don't think there is a neuter gender in Hebrew, so "them" may be able to refer to either one.  Still, context implies that it refers to the people and not the fortifications.

The next phrase strengthens that theory.

> as we did to Shilon king of Hebron

It makes more sense that it's saying that they defeated the king Og and his men as they did to king Shilon and his men than that it's saying that they defeated the city's fortifications as they did to king Shilon.

Them most likely refers to King Og and his men mentioned in verse 1.